# Data type of variable size in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, types

In Java I want to create a data type, let's say Atom, which contains an index number, and when that index = 0, the Atom will contain a String datum, otherwise the Atom is just an index (Integer).

How can I do that?

I guess it would save some space if most Atoms are just indexes and only some contain Strings.

Comment: Are you meaning to create a class?

Comment: you could have two classes: `SimpleAtom` with an `int` and `ComplexAtom extends SimpleAtom` with a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Factory Pattern illustrates how a static factory method `createAtom` creates instances of different classes (all Atom), with different data.

Here I made index `final` as changing it to 0, will not change the class of the object. Also Atom has to offer access to the optional datum.

```
public class Atom {
    public final int index;

    private Atom(int ix) {
        this.index = ix;
    }

    public String getDatum() {
        return null;
    }

    public static Atom createAtom(int index) {
        return index != 0 ? new Atom(index) : new ExtendedAtom(index);
    }
}

class ExtendedAtom extends Atom {
    private String datum;

    ExtendedAtom(int ix) {
        super(ix);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make a single class like that, because Java does not support "union" types. If you define a class with an `int` and a `String`, the space for both the `int` and the reference to a `String` would be allocated, defeating the space-saving purpose of what you are trying to achieve.

You could store your "atoms" as `java.lang.Object` values, but you would need to check their type and cast every time you need to obtain the index or the string. This approach is cumbersome, because primitive `int`s are wrapped in `java.lang.Integer` objects, adding to storage requirements.

A cleaner approach would be defining an interface for your `Atom`, and defining two classes, a `StringAtom` and an `IntAtom`, to store the two atom kinds in your program:

```
interface Atom {
    boolean hasInt();
    boolean hasString();
    int getInt();
    String getString();
}
class StringAtom implements Atom {
    private final String s;
    public StringAtom(String s) {this.s = s;}
    boolean hasInt() {return false;}
    boolean hasString() {return true;}
    int getInt() {throw new IllegalStateException();}
    String getString() {return s;}
}
class IntAtom implements Atom {
    private final int n;
    public IntAtom(int n) {this.b = b;}
    boolean hasInt() {return true;}
    boolean hasString() {return false;}
    int getInt() {return n;}
    String getString() {throw new IllegalStateException();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a small class with an index member variable, a flag checking if that index is zero and a String datum that will be non-null only if the flag is true (indicating the index is zero).